# How to set value according to model in bootstrap slider bar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

`$("#sliderAcceleration").data("slider").value(@Model.Acceleration);`

This is not working , Please suggest any answer.

Comment: checked your console ?

Comment: ya it says .value() is undefined